# Wordpress 404 with custom .htaccess rewrite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to do an internal redirect so

> /dev/spares/whatever

is

> /dev/spares/?pid=whatever

But maintains the directory URL /dev/spares/whatever front end. This works with numbers fine in my .htaccess code shown below.

> /dev/spares/12345

However if I use any text

> /dev/spares/whatever123

it gives a 404. I think this is Wordpress thinking it is a sub-page but I don't know how to get around this? Can I make an exception somehow?

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dev/
# My rewrite for internal query string
RewriteRule ^spares/([^/]+) spares/\?pid=$1 [NC]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dev/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and I use a custom permalink structure in Wordpress of:

> /%category%/%postname%/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247573/rewriterule-accepts-numbers-but-not-letters-in-tag

Using the Wordpress function:

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    return add_rewrite_rule(
        'spares/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=spares&pid=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
});

add_filter('query_vars', function($v){ return array_merge(array('pid'),$v); });
```